# How to reorder TMUX sessions?

Tags: tmux

Is there any way to re-number or swap tmux sessions, just as you can renumber or swap tmux windows? I can't see any command for it and want to easily switch between certain sessions.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They're sorted by name (which defaults to a number)  You can change the names so that they appear in the order that you prefer.

Outside of tmux:

`tmux rename-session -t 0 zzz`

inside tmux:
`C-b $`

Or:

`c-b : rename session -t current_name new_name`

Comment: They're not anymore. I named all of my sessions, and they're definitely not alphabetically sorted.

Comment: It seems sessions are being ordered by index now (i.e. the order they're created). You can type `O` while in session list mode to cycle through the different sort orderings (including `sort: name`), however I haven't figured out how to persist this setting.

Comment: @Cody you can add `bind s choose-tree -sZ -O name` to your tmux config to persist this setting. There's also 2 other options: `time` to sort from most to least recently used sessions and `index` to sort by creation date (i guess)

Answer (score 29):

The default ordering seems to have changed recently from name to index. If you want to put it back to name, try this in your .tmux.conf

```
bind s choose-tree -sZ -O name
```

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like to "manually" order your sessions, you can prefix the session name with a [zero-width or invisible unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=INVISIBLE+%7C+ZERO+WIDTH&preview=none). For example:

```
$ tmux rename-session -t charlie $(echo -e "\u200B")charlie
$ tmux rename-session -t beta $(echo -e "\u200C")beta
$ tmux rename-session -t alpha $(echo -e "\u200D")alpha
$ tmux list-sessions
charlie: 1 windows (created Sun Nov  2 12:39:30 2014) [284x87] (attached)
beta: 1 windows (created Sun Nov  2 12:39:27 2014) [284x87]
alpha: 1 windows (created Sun Nov  2 12:39:23 2014) [284x87]
```

The drawback is that you still have to refer to the session using those characters.

Comment: This sounds terrible.